# Laravel 5.3 set homepage as login screen

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

How do I set the homepage (`/`) to the login screen in Laravel 5.3?

I have a routes file :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I have set up the basic auth scaffolding with the command `php artisan make:auth` and have set up my db tables too.

But I'm struggling to understand how to set the homepage to always go to the login screen if the user is not authenticated? Surely this is just me being stupid right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just needed to specify the `middleware('auth')` for my route:

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    })->middleware('auth');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

This way if you're not logged in it will redirect to login automatically.

Comment: This worked for me and  Ir moved ->middleware('auth')

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
   });
});
```

Just put all the routes that needed authentication inside that middleware group.

Answer (score 3):

in laravel in general you can change the url view path to what you want as example

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.4 you can modify the route as
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');